# Comparison Test for Improper integrals with result of indeterminate form

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int^3_1\dfrac1{x-1}dx$$ I use the integral union property to break the integral into a limit from $0$ to $1$ and $1$ to $3$ since $x$ cannot be integrated at $x=1$. Then, I solve both integrals and I'm left with $\infty-\infty$which is again indeterminate form... How do I resolve this?

Comment: First of all, if you're trying to compute $\int_1^3 \frac 1 {x - 1} \, dx$ as you say in your first line, then there is *no* reason to integrate over $[0, 1]$ as well. Secondly, once one of the two integrals is divergent, the overall integral is divergent. This is a general fact about improper Riemann integrals.

Comment: Really? So I just need to integrate over the original integral notice it goes to infinity bc of V.A. therefore it's diverging?

Comment: Sort of; having a vertical asymptote does *not* imply that the integral is divergent, though.

Comment: I made a mistake. The integral's upper limit is 3, but the lower limit is 0. That is why I split the integral into two parts. What would the answer be now?

Comment: See the second sentence in my last comment.........

Comment: No... I learned that you still have to check for the second integrals result. Only if it was a constant, then you can assume it's divergent. But, if it's minus infinity, then infinity minus infinity leads to indeterminate form.

Comment: In that case, I think you've learned it incorrectly
. A condition for convergence is that **both** one-sided limits exist and that **both** are finite.

Comment: Yes.. I understand how convergence works... But this is the case of divergence. You could be right, but my professor taught this to a class of 600 so I doubt it's incorrect.

Comment: In this case by definition the integral is assumed to be not convergent.

Comment: What is far more likely is that you've misunderstood something your professor said, or that there was a miscommunication. The definition of convergence **requires** that both one-sided limits exist and are finite; neither one-sided limit is finite here, so the integral diverges. And as soon as you know one of the two isn't finite, the integral diverges.

Comment: @DaquarisGeorgino Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work